# Django form submission redirecting to wrong url

Tags: python, django, web, django-views, django-forms

I am trying to take help from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FN3EfKC2i6M&t=3669s) tutorial and my own thing. It's supposed to be a marketplace.

I have an app called Creator (vendors)

- I am trying to let the users add new products by themselves using
  `views.add_product`, `add_product.html`, and `forms.py`

when I try to submit the `add_product` form, it gives this error

Error
`Page not found (404) Request Method: POST Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/creator/`

(I am not trying to redirect it to this page but rather `'url 'creator_overview''`

Project's urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('core.urls')),
    path('creator/', include('creator.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

creator/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [

    path('sell_on_cosloo/', sell_great_things, name='creator_signup'),
    path('creator_overview/',creator_overview , name='creator_overview'),
    path('add_product/',add_product , name='add_product'),
...
]
```

creator/views.py

```
@login_required
def add_product(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProductForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            product = form.save(commit=False)
            product.creator = request.user.creator
            product.slug = slugify(product.title)
            product.save()

            return redirect('creator_overview')
    else:
        form = ProductForm()
    
    return render(request, 'creator/add_product.html', {'form': form})
```

creator/forms.py

```
<form method="post" action="." enctype="multipart/form-data">

  
    {% csrf_token %}

    {{ form.as_p }}

    <div class="field">
        <div class="control">
            <button class="button is-dark is-uppercase">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

add_product.html

```
{% extends 'core/base.html' %} {% block title %}Add product | {% endblock %} {%
block content %}

<h1 class="title">Add product</h1>

<form method="post" action="." enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {% csrf_token %} {{ form.as_p }}

  <div class="field">
    <div class="control">
      <button class="button is-dark is-uppercase">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Peace!! :))

Edit : Okay quick update: I think its something related to the images, I removed the image field from the form and now it seems to be working as its supposed to

Comment: Yes but your pattern from the root url (e.g. above creator) states that you need /creator/creator_overview/. Also I'm pretty sure you need slashes at the end too - e.g. creator_overview/, not just creator_overview.

Comment: I think I added the slashes at the end and retested, thank you.
(The error still persists)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the **action attribute** in the form.

Instead of :

```
<form method="post" action="." enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Here the form will try to be submitted on  ***http://127.0.0.1:8000/creator/*** url that is not correct

Try this :

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'add_product' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

The correct url is ***http://127.0.0.1:8000/creator/add_product/*** as defined in the *creator/urls.py* file

Comment: Hi, thank you, 
it's strange that,

The page is now redirected to the "add_product" page, even after I change the action back to " .", and not the old one( /creator)


Also, it's not redirecting to "creators_overview after submission and the product which is supposed to be saved if the form is valid doesn't seem to be happening.

Comment: The submit button, you wrote `<button class="button is-dark is-uppercase">Submit</button>` but you forgot to specify the type : `<button class="button is-dark is-uppercase" type='submit'>Submit</button>`

Comment: oh, I think it's working now. I am a newbie at this and I think I should understand the basics better. I should mention that it's working with action = ".", Also, I didn't realize the tutorial code was missing type="submit" too. Thank you :))